# Delphi IdSNMP on android or is there a truly portable delphi snmp solution

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe7, indy10

Has anyone been able to use idSNMP for Android target (Delphi XE7..10). I have a working app under WinXX and IOS but wont work under android

> Error #13 access denied AND/OR could not bind to socket

Just looking for a solution that will work across targets. Synapse works great for WINXX and Linux with Lazarus, but wont work with Delphi mobile somewhat thanks for the brilliant idea to drop support for ansistring which makes porting old code a project in itself (ByteString patch wont help either) turns out that with indy under Lazarus on Linux gives the same error occurs unless the app is run as root..... And yes, the manifest includes network access. has anyone got any idea?

EDIT

```
const
  oid_DeviceMake = '1.3.6.1.4.1.1206.4.2.6.1.3.1.3.1';

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdSNMP1.Host:= '192.168.2.167';
  IdSNMP1.Port:= 161;
  IdSNMP1.Community:= 'public';
  IdSNMP1.Active:= true;

  label1.Text:= '';

  IdSNMP1.Query.Clear;
  IdSNMP1.Query.PDUType:= PDUGetRequest;
  IdSNMP1.Query.MIBAdd(oid_DeviceMake, '', ASN1_NULL);

  if IdSNMP1.SendQuery then
  begin
    label1.Text:= IdSNMP1.Reply.MIBGet(oid_DeviceMake);
  end;

  IdSNMP1.Active:= false;
end;
```

I have found this morning that with Delphi XE7 setting the TrapPort to 0 will let this code work. The Access denied occurs when trying to bind the trap port in "function TIdSNMP.GetBinding: TIdSocketHandle;" if it is 0 then no binding is attempted.

Under Delphi DX the code will work 1 out of 3 calls with trap port to 162 ?? setting trapport to 0 and it will work 1 out of 2 calls ??. others return Bind error, address and port already in use. Since I only installed DX trial, I cannot tell what happens as it does no come with sources but from the difference something changed between versions

It all works fine under windows and IOS.

Comment: Please show your actual code. `TIdSNMP` is an ordinary UDP client, it doesn't do anything weird with the socket that should be restricting access. Maybe there is an issue with your Android device instead. You do have the `INTERNET` permission enabled in your app manifest, right?

Comment: Original question edited

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. Ports below 1024 are **privileged** in *Nix systems (Android has a Linux core), where binding a socket to a privileged port requires root access. It is a security feature to prevent non-root users from running malicious servers on well-known ports. Windows and iOS do not have that restriction.